# The 16th Century Poem "Western Wind" - first two lines

Tags: syntactic-analysis

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westron_Wynde):

> Westron wynde when wyll thow blow
> the smalle rayne downe can Rayne
> Cryst yf my love were in my Armys
> And I yn my bed Agayne.

Can not the words "when", or "so", be inferred between the first two lines?  I too have pondered this question for some 60 years since first hearing the Limeliters' recorded version of this song.

Thanks for posting all regarding this poem. I had no idea of the age of this poem and these posts confirm what I thought that I heard in the song.

I believe that some poems should not or need not be parsed completely: some meanings ought to be guessed at or be free to be interpreted, which is sometimes the author's intention.

Comment: Roughly: *When will you blow, Wind, such that a small rain can rain down?* https://www.jstor.org/stable/2872415

Comment: Note that a [variant of this lyric](https://books.google.com/books?id=VOUsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA122&dq=%22westron+wynde%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSmbLV2p6CAxXDHjQIHYMPAZk4ChDoAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22westron%20wynde%22&f=false) runs as follows: "Westron wynde, when wilt thou blow? / The small rain down can rain! / O gentle death, when wilt thou come? / For I of my life am weary."

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that the words express sentiments that we can all get behind and are spoken by some young man who is working out in the open in poor weather.

> Westron wynde when wyll thow blow
>
> the smalle rayne downe can Rayne
>
> Cryst yf my love were in my Armys
>
> And I yn my bed Agayne

O Western wind! When will you blow?

The drizzle knows how to rain down!

Christ! If only my love were in my arms

And I were in my bed again.

Wikipedia informs that the words are several centuries earlier than the date of publication, thus:

> **OED**
>
> **II.i.5.a. Expressing physical or mental ability:** be able to, **know how to**; have the power, ability, or capacity to.
>
> c1225 (?c1200) *Constu bulden abur inwið iþin heorte?* [Do you know
> how to build an arbor in your heart?] St. Katherine (Royal MS.) (1981)
> l. 762
>
> c1475 (?c1451) *To can renne withe speer.* [to know how to charge with
> a speer] Boke of Noblesse (Royal MS.) (1860) 76

[my translation]

Comment: Is "can" expressing knowledge or ability? I thought it was more like "It can rain as much as it likes!"/"Let it rain!" Can=permission; or maybe an implied conditional ("It can rain however much, I won't care/change"). In the UK the west wind usually brings rain because it comes from the Atlantic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Middle English speaker, but I don't think a preposition is needed there. "the small rain" is the direct object of the verb "blow", so it's asking when will the wind blow the small rain down.

Comment: But if your interpretation is "West wind, when will you blow the small rain down?", what about "can Rayne" at the end of the second line? Is it separate?

Comment: I'm guessing "can Rayne" means "on Rayne"